# How to achieve this type type of context menu in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu

Whenever I connect a context menu to a notification icon in vb.net, I always get one of this type:[image]

But in most programs, I find this type of context menu:[image].

The differences are,

1. The direction of the menu in my case is right to left but in the other case, it is left to right (I don't mean the text appears from right to left).
2. The one in my case is a little whiter and the other is kinda of 'control' color.
3. The one in my case is a bit slower than the other (i.e. it takes a little more time to show up).

Does anyone know (is it possible) how to add a menu like the second one ?

Comment: 1. Not sure that is true.  It appears that yours would not fit on the screen if the right edge was at the edge of the icon.     2) They look the same to me.         3)  Is there a delay property you can fiddle with?

Comment: 1. Yes it is true 2. They are not same 3. No delay property (AFAIK)

Comment: The other applications are probably not written in .Net.  If you don't like the default .Net control then either change to a different language or buy some kind of third party control to use.  The delay is most likely due to .Net loading the library for the first time.  After the initial delay, does the menu popup much faster on subsequent clicks?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Oh, thanks for the response! (+1) Yes, I see the delay only on the first click. And probably you are right, many programs are written in languages other than .NET. I don't have such a big problem with the menu, so I'll be going with the default. I wonder why a MS product doesn't offer flexibility in changing the behavior of a MS UI control. Anyway, thanks!